# Heat asymptotics

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

Consider a compact manifold $M$ with smooth boundary, with either the Dirichlet or the Neumann boundary conditions. Consider a (time-dependent) open ball $B_t \subset M$. Given a fixed $u \in L^1(M)$, can we choose $\eta > 0$ such that 
$$\Vert e^{t\Delta}u\Vert_{L^1(M \setminus B_t)} \leq C\Vert u\Vert_{L^1(M \setminus B_t)}$$
whenever $t < \eta$ and $C$ is independent of $t$ and $B_t$ shrinks to a point as $t \to 0$?

Edit: in the interest of specificity, let us say that $B_t = B_t(y)$, a ball of radius $t$ about a fixed point $y \in M$.

Comment: If $u$ is supported in $B$, then your RHS is zero but LHS is not.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Actually it is supported outside $B$ too. But now I have edited the question to make it more precise.

Comment: Suppose the estimate holds for a fixed $t>0$. Then replace your favorite $u$ with $u+k\phi$ for $\phi$ supported in $B_t$. If you now let $k\to\infty$, RHS remains bounded but LHS doesn't seem to. I think you need to specify what you assume of $u$, the time dependence of $B_t$ and what $C$ is allowed to depend on.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Sorry, I meant given a fixed $u \in L^1$, I did not want that the estimate should go through for all $u \in L^1$. I have edited the question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Since we are on a compact setting, shouldn't the result follow from the pointwise convergence $e^{t\Delta} u \to u$ as $t \to 0$?

Comment: Perhaps, but you need to be more careful with the formulation of your question. The exact quantifier order is not at all clear, nor is the time dependence of $B_t$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta A further edit. Sorry I am new to this site, I realize I had to be more precise.

Comment: If $u$ is fixed, there might be a problem as $t\to \infty$. E.g. if $u$ is supported in $B_T \subsetneq M$, then the RHS will be $0$ before the LHS. But as long as $\eta$ is such that $||e^{t\Delta}u||_{M\setminus B_t}/||u||_{M\setminus B_t}$ is defined for $t\leq \eta$, you should be okay, since (as you pointed out) this goes to $1$ as $t\to 0$.